# Upgrade php version on ZPanel

Tags: centos, upgrade

how to update the PHP version to 5.4 or 5.5 ZPanel running on CentOS? I will be happy for any tips and manuals. I found no reply to this topic. thank you

Comment: were you able to find the solution? plz share 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 6.x x86_64 (64-bit)

Step 1

wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm

Step 2

Now enable your newly added Remi repo. Open the /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo repository file using a text editor of your choice

vi /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo

Step 4

Edit enabled=0 line to enabled=1:

[image: PHP]

Update to PHP 5.4, in [remi] section:

Update to PHP 5.5, in [remi-php55] section:

Update to PHP 5.6 (beta version), in [remi-php56] section:

Save and Quit.

Step 5

yum update -y

Step 6

php -v

Thats all